# powershell scriptblock returns NULL eventhough it shouldn't

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

I am trying to understand why in the following example the script-block returning a List-object returns null. Eventhough with other types it works perfectly fine.

```
$s1 = {
    param($string);
  $list = [System.Collections.Generic.List[object]]::new();
    return $list; 
}
$s2 = {
    param($string);
  return 'test'; 
}

$r1 = (Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock ($s1) -ArgumentList('something'));
$r2 = (Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock ($s2) -ArgumentList('something'));
write-host ($null -eq $r1); # True
write-host ($null -eq $r2); # False
write-host ($r1); # <empty>
write-host ($r2); # test
```

The result from the above snippet is:

```
True
False

test
```

I would expect:

```
False
False
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Object]
test
```

Can somebody help me understand why the `$s1` scriptblock would return `$null`?

Comment: Classic PowerShell gotha, use the [unary comma](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators#format-operator--f): `return ,$list; `

Comment: FYI: [PowerShell Gotchas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69617202/1701026)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PowerShell loves to *enumerate* (or *unroll*) collections, including `[List]`'s, which is exactly what happens here.

To suppress this behavior, use `Write-Output -NoEnumerate`:

```
$s1 = {
    param($string)
    $list = [System.Collections.Generic.List[object]]::new()
    return Write-Output $list -NoEnumerate
}
```

Comment: That seems to do the trick, thanks powershell for this weirdness :P. But just to understand it better. 'unroll' means converting it to a pipe-line (e.i. I could use `Foreach-Object` on it)?

Comment: @n247s Well, the inverse - the auto-unrolling happens primarily so that `ForEach-Object` (and other cmdlets) can consume pipeline input 1-by-1

Comment: The idea behind the [PowerShell Pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pipelines) is to unravel any collections and pass (stream) each individual item to a number of consecutive [cmdlets](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/scripting/developer/cmdlet/cmdlet-overview) similar to workstations in a manufacturing line.